# replace values in a jsonb array

Tags: postgresql

I have a jsonb[] column that holds JSON arrays.

A sample record would be like this:

```sql
[
  {"name":"Sam","url":"example.om/sam"},
  {"name":"Dan","url":"example.om/dan"}
]
```

I want to replace `example.om` with `example.com` everywhere in this column.

I figured the easiest way was if I treated the jsonb as a text and do a string replace, but I am having trouble converting back to jsonb. What I have so far:

```
update table tb
set users = replace(users, 'example.om', 'example.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

Working solution:

```
update my_table
set users = replace(users::text, 'example.om', 'example.com')::jsonb[]
```